# Listview not getting updated

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, fragment

I have a Listview in MyTaskFragment extends Fragment class which displays the task name and the status of the task. When I click on the particular row of the listview I get an activity named MyTaskonClick   where I can update the status of the task. The problem is that  after I close the activity the status does not get updated on the listview in MytaskFragment. Can anyone suggest a solution. My codes are as follows:

```
public class MyTaskFragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);
    Databasehandler db=new Databasehandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    final ListView l=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewmytask);


        int count=db.getcounttask();
        if(count==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Task to Display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
    if(id.compareTo("empty")!=0)
    {
        val1.clear();
    val1=db.getTaskReceived(id);


     ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val1,R.layout.mytask,new String[]{"TaskId","heading","status"},new int[]{R.id.View1,R.id.View2,R.id.ViewStatus});

    l.setAdapter(k);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "arg2"+val1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv2=(TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.View1);
            String t=tv2.getText().toString();
             Intent i4=new Intent(getActivity(),Mytaskonclick.class);
                i4.putExtra("taskId",t);
                // startActivityForResult(i4, 0);
                   startActivity(i4);
        }
    });

        }
    return rootView;
```

}

Mytaskonclick.class
 s1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sentstatus);
            tv.setText("accepted");
            queryValues.put("status","accepted");
            queryValues.put("taskid",id);
            db.updateTask(queryValues);
            //Log.w("id",""+id+queryValues);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few options:

- Override `onResume()` and refresh your `ListView` in it (but care about not refreshing it both when you start the activity for the first time).
- Start the activity using `startActivityForResult(...)` and override `onActivityResult(...)` in the activity/fragment containing the `ListView` and refresh it at that moment.

To refresh, you have to call `listView.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: listView.notifyDataSetChanged() didn't help

Comment: It probably means you're not updating the model or that the adapter is not aware of the changes you made in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Using `startActivityForResult(i4, 0);` and then in your `onActivityResult()` call to `getListView().invalidateVìews();`

Comment: If you use that method, do not use `0` in the `startActivityForResult` method but have a constant somewhere. This code is reused in the `onActivityResult()` method to identify where you're back from.

Comment: I cant use getListview() as I am using a fragment

Comment: Oh! I see you are not using a ListFragment , I recommend you changing `Fragment` for `ListFragment` if you dont want to do it then call to `ListView l=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewmytask);l.invalidateViews();`

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayAdapter instead of ListAdapter.